# How do I call the new function in R when the object is defined in another package?

Tags: r, class, package

Suppose I'm creating a package and I'd like to define a function that creates an object where the object is defined in another package.

For example:

`get_empty_mtx <- function() return(new("dgCMatrix"))`

If I type `library(Matrix)`, this will work, but when I'm making my own package, I like to use `::` when referencing things from other packages.  I can't do `Matrix::new("dgCMatrix")` as new is not a function from the Matrix package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getClassDef` function to get a class definition from a specific package and then call `new()` on that. For example

```
new(getClassDef("dgCMatrix", getNamespace("Matrix")))
```

and `new(getClassDef("dgCMatrix", "Matrix"))` also seems to work despite the documtation saying `where` should be an environment.